# PHP Curl how to handle data response

Tags: php, curl

I have sort php code using curl for get a web page.

```
$url = "http://google.com";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
exit;
```

and here is the full reponse from google.

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

But now i don't want CURL get full page from google, i just want get response from `<HTML>` to `<H1>301 Moved</H1>` and stop curl response and close connection.

Anyone can help me to do this?

Comment: You can't receive just "part of the response"... you send the request, then receive the full result. If you want to use only part of the response, you'll have to parse it

Comment: @Bartdude, yes you can. `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` (or, since it's the response status he seems to be after, `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`) is what OP needs.

Comment: @lafor > well the part of code he needs is in the body so getting only the header wouldn't be enough, but maybe you're right that the OP actually wants the status, not the content...

Comment: @Bartdude In this particular case it would, since this is a standard HTML returned along with 301 Redirect status. That said, it's possible to read the response stream in chunks and abort at any moment, so claiming that you can only "receive the full result" is wrong.

Comment: @lafor you can show me an example for how to using `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` for stop curl response when contains `<H1>301 Moved</H1>`?

Comment: @lafor > I may have misinterpreted the OP's need, but you're right that he could get a part of the response, expressed in bytes... that said, it is still unclear what the OP wants to do. If he wants to get the `<h1>` part of the body, then even getting a certain amount of bytes wouldn't be enough as you can never be sure if this tag will be contained in those bytes...

Answer (score 1):

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` will have cURL follow any 301/302 redirects.

Comment: Wont that just have CURL return the rest of the next page though? In this case the google home page?

Comment: No, i mean stop curl response when contains = `<H1>301 Moved</H1>`

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, this is a fair remark regarding OP's example, as there's probably not much interrest in getting the "redirect" response, but rather the final page response...